# Equivalence among three kinds of mass

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, mass, definition, inertia

If there are three kinds of mass

(1) resistance (classical inertial mass, rest mass)
(2) sensitivity to gravity (weight)
(3) creation of gravity,

the Eotvos experiment shows the proportionality between (1) and (2).

Can we think the Cavendish experiment and the slowing of binary solar stars show the proportionality between (1) and (3) implicitly?

Or I suspect the three definitions have some flaw.

Comment: Types of mass (2) and (3) are sometimes referred to as passive and active gravitational masses.

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you. I felt safe to know there are proper terms.